# Android - App is incompatible with all device

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest

App which is published in Google play is not compatible with any of the real device. I wanted to support all real devices except small screens. Following is the manifest that I configured accordingly. After publishing to Google Play, I realize that it is not compatible with any device.

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.work.mob"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="0.15" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <compatible-screens>
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="ldpi"
            android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="mdpi"
            android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="hdpi"
            android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
            android:screenSize="normal" />
    </compatible-screens>

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="false"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
        android:allowBackup="true" >
        <service android:name="com.work.mob.time.Downloads" >
        </service>

        <activity
            android:name="com.work.mob.time.active.LoginActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Kindly suggest.

Comment: Start [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html) and move through the tutorial please

Comment: What you're seeing is most likely a hiccup on the Play Store's side. Check back with it later. That being said, I would *strongly* encourage you to remove the `<compatible-screens>` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the compatible-screens element.

Replace the supports-screens with:

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="false"/>
```